# Why does my GAE Flexible App responds to HTTP requests on port 8080 automatically?

Tags: google-app-engine

I deployed a GAE Flexible App built on SpringBoot successfully on GAE Flex environment but if I set the app to run on port 8090, sending a request to the App gives a 502(Bad Gateway). Setting the port to 8080 responds to the requests successfully.

I specified Port Forwarding in the Firewall rule which seems to be useless.

So the question is,

Why does my GAE Flexible App responds to HTTP requests on port 8080 automatically?

And,

Is there no way to use any other port for my Application?

Comment: how you set the app to run on 8090?

Comment: @KhalilM : By setting server.port = 8090 in application.properties config file in SpringBoot. I tested locally and it does get deployed to 8090.

Comment: Google App Engine only proxies applications running on port 8080, and I believe 80 as well, through to port 443 (HTTPS). Theoretically, it's possible to access ports directly with the IP but I'm having issues deploying with the port forwarding rules required for this to work so maybe not...? Would be good to have a Googler answer this question.